# Retrieve an instance of an entity when the entity is partially called

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a page that displays information about a single film and offers to leave a comment. In order to display the comments specific to each film, I proceeded in this way :

```php
   /**
     * @Route("film/{id}", name="film")
     */
    public function film(FilmRepository $repo, EntityManagerInterface $em, Request $req, $id)
    {
        $film = $repo->find($id);

        $comments = $film->getComments();

        $comment = new Comment;
        $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($req);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $comment->setAuthor($this->getUser());
            $comment->setFilm($id);
            $em->persist($comment);
            $em->flush();

        }





        return $this->render('film/film.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'FilmController',
            'film' => $film,
            'comments' => [$comments],
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

I thought that passing the $id variable (which I get and which corresponds to the film id) would be enough. But I get the error:

***Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Comment::setFilm() must be an instance of App\Entity\Film or null, integer given, called in /home/""""/projet-film2/src/Controller/FilmController.php on line 61***

The error is fairly self-explanatory and speaks for itself. I would have to instantiate a new movie object, get its movie->getId() id, and pass it as a setter parameter. But since the film is already instantiated here, that might complicate things, right? **Is there a way to get around this problem in a way other than instantiating ?**

Comment: Your controllers aren’t supposed to contain any logic.

Comment: So what's your suggest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simply to **inject the dependency**, then pass it to the setter :

```php
   /**
     * @Route("film/{id}", name="film")
     */
    public function film(FilmRepository $repo, Film $film, EntityManagerInterface $em, Request $req, $id)
    {
        $filmRepo = $repo->find($id);

        $comments = $filmRepo->getComments();

        $comment = new Comment;
        $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);
        $form->handleRequest($req);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $comment->setAuthor($this->getUser());
            $comment->setFilm($film);

            $em->persist($comment);
            $em->flush();

        }

        return $this->render('film/film.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'FilmController',
            'film' => $film,
            'comments' => [$comments],
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```